# install composer-cli at v0.19 or higher

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

When i tried to execute createPeerAdminCard shell i encountered below error.

```
No version of composer-cli has been detected, you need to install composer-cli at v0.19 or higher
```

I have composer-cli installed

```
+ composer-cli@0.19.10 version
nvm version 0.33.8
npm version 5.6.0
node version 8.9.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you already have a look at this?

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#installissues

It is recommended to use npm version 8.9.x for composer.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

> npm config get prefix

This will give your npm path.

It can give something like: `/usr/local/share/npm`

Write the following command on your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file or simply run the command on your terminal:

> export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"

After that:

- open a new tab or window of the terminal
- go to your fabric directory where you have the file `createPeerAdminCard.sh`
- and run:

> ./createPeerAdminCard.sh

Now, it should run fine without the '`composer-cli not found`' error.